# What does Islam say about Superstiotns

Tags: sin

Things like breaking mirrors bringing bad luck and such I only ask for educational purposes and nothing else thank you for you're answers Ive Just never found a answer on this topic before

Comment: Hello and welcome to [islam.se]. This question shows severe lack of research-prior-asking. Questions on this site are expected to be well researched. Please also go through [ask] and the [help/on-topic] to see what type of questions are expected here. Try [edit]ing the question and the question could be re-opened. Adding you own research effort is more likely to attract quality answers.

Answer (score 1):

There is ***no might or power*** without Allah.

Attributing -for example- a black cat bringing bad luck is an act of *Shirk* (Associating power to other then Allah). This is forbidden and constitutes the biggest sin.

> It was narrated that ‘Abd-Allaah ibn Mas’ood said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: **“Tiyarah (superstitious belief in omens) is shirk.”** Narrated by al-Tirmidhi (1614), Abu Dawood (3910), Ibn Majaah (3538); classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh Abi Dawood.